# Variables used in the nested for statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function abc()
{
    var str = "";  //  -------------------(4) 
    for (var i = 0; i < 100 ; i++)
    {
        str = "<tr><td>"; // ------------------(1)
            for(var m = 1 ; m <= cnt_chapter ; m++)
        {
            str = str + "<span>" + m +"</span> "; //  -------------(2) 
        }
        str = str + "</td></tr>"; // ------------(3) 
    }                       
    $(".title").append(str);
}
```

This code is part of jquery code.
I want to make code between  (1) and (3)

But don't work (2) code.

What is the wrong of my code?

Comment: i) Semicolons are missing in 3 places : str = "<tr><td>", 2 and 3 ii) What does your error console say?

Comment: As @undefined mentioned, use += instead of = in (1).

Comment: @TJ-: Semicolon terminators are mostly optional in JavaScript. Leaving them out isn't a good idea but they are not required.

Comment: okay. thanks for that. I remember facing troubles when not using semicolons. I guess the issue would have been something else.

Comment: hyekyung you can checkout the demo, your problem has been resolved I guess, check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cnt_chapter` is undifiend here also problem with append

```
var cnt_chapter = 10;
function abc()
{
    var str = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < 10 ; i++)
    {
        str += "<tr><td>";
        for(var m = 1 ; m <= cnt_chapter ; m++)
        {
            str = str + "<span>" + m +"</span> ";
        }
        str = str + "</td></tr>";
    }                       
     $(".title").append(str);
}

abc();
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VdSGS/1/)

Comment: It could be defined outside the context of the function.

Comment: from this example it is not defined and you can't jut down vote for it.

Comment: the downvote was for not actually fixing the problem, which is the incorrect assignment `str = "<tr><td>"` that overwrites all previous contents.

Comment: To define/ debug exact problem you need working code as demo...

Answer (score 2):

```
function abc()
{
    var str = "";  //  -------------------(4) 
    for (var i = 0; i < 100 ; i++)
    {
        str += "<tr><td>"; // ------------------(1)
            for(var m = 1 ; m <= cnt_chapter ; m++)
        {
            str += "<span>" + m +"</span> "; //  -------------(2) 
        }
        str += "</td></tr>"; // ------------(3) 
    }                       
    $(".title").append(str);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
function abc() {
    var str = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < 100 ; i++) {
        str += "<tr><td>";
        for(var m = 1 ; m <= cnt_chapter ; m++){ 
            str = str + "<span>" + m +"</span> ";
        }
        str += "</td></tr>";
    }
    $(".title").append(str);
}
```

Note that you need to preserve the HTML from the previous iteration, so you should append the `<tr>` to the existing `str` value, instead of replacing it.

Comment: Could you please also leave a comment explaining the downvote?

Comment: 1. explanation poorly hidden in the code, 2. inefficient code, causing 100 evaluations of `$('.title')` and 100 separate DOM insertions instead of just 1.

Answer (score 0):

You're erasing the string each time around the outer loop, so it only ever has one HTML row in it.

Your line tagged `(1)` should also be using `str = str + ...`, not `str = ...`

Comment: This is probably the 500th time I've had to say this in the past week, but I didn't downvote you. I almost never downvote.

Comment: Here's an upvote to prove it (besides the fact that the answer is correct)

Comment: Whoever is down voting, he has no excuse... infact problem has been solved.

Comment: wow, two downvotes, two upvotes.  And this was (until they fixed their answers following my comments) the only correct answer.  **NB** for simple problems like this it is not necessary to post working code, nor demos - just instructions on what went wrong.  Sometimes it's better _not_ to just "show me the code"

Answer (score 0):

Although this is a poorly written code, the reason why its not getting executed is that the variable `cnt_chapter` is not defined. People have mentioned that there are no semi-colons in place, and that the string being built is being replaced in the outer loop, etc. These are logical errors. And even with these logical errors, had the variable `cnt_chapter` been declared and initialized correctly, the code should have very well executed to produce some wrong results.

Comment: how do you know it wasn't defined elsewhere?

Comment: Alnitak, there seems to be an ambiguity in his question and the code he has posted. It does not mention about the variable anywhere neither is there any declaration. And looking at his question, its obvious it wasn't defined elsewhere. Had it been defined, he would not have had the problem in the first place.